# How to take the data of a specific column in firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the data of the column `name`. I have the table `users` and inside it has the columns `name`, `email` and `phone_number`

The code below is what I used to take the table `users` and the `key` or the id of the row. This is almost identical to the delete code where I use `ref('users/'+key).remove()` for that matter

```
async print(key) {
  console.log(firebase.database().ref('users/'+key))
}
```

I expect the output of `name` for example 'John'

Comment: You may have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have read that and I still don't get it

Comment: Is this ionic oriented documentation more adapted? https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/building-a-ionic-firebase-app-step-by-step

Comment: You are logging only the reference of the data, to get the actual data, you need to follow the instructions in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is the reference.

You need to do .once('value') to get a snapshot at that reference, then do .val() on that snapshot to get the data

```
async print(key) 
{
  const name = await firebase.database().ref('users/'+key).once('value')
  console.log(name.val()))
}
```

Comment: I got what I need because of you. Thank you